# R raster plotting an image, draw a circle and mask pixels outside circle

Tags: r, image, mask, raster

Code below plots an image and then plots circle on that image. I want to make all pixels that fall outside that circle black. How could I do that?

```
library(raster)
library(plotrix)
r1 <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
width=50
height=40
x <- crop(r1, extent(0,width,0,height))
plotRGB(x)
circlex=20
circley=15
radius=10
draw.circle(circlex,circley,radius,border="blue")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the 'x'-object with str() and you see this:

```
..@ data    :Formal class '.MultipleRasterData' [package "raster"] with 14 slots
  .. .. ..@ values    : num [1:2500, 1:3] 255 248 221 199 198 210 221 190 104 79 ...
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "red" "green" "blue"
```

....so the 1:50 by 1:50 values are mapped to three columns. The X values are probably `0:2500 %% 50` and the y values are probably `0:2500 %/% 50`

So remembering that the "origin" if upper left corner for raster objects but the lower left corner for plot functions, and so the y-value of 20 becomes 50-20 or 30, this gives you close to what you ask for (with apologies for putting the y-sequence first):

```
x@data@values[( ((1:2500 %/% 50 )- 30)^2 + ((1:2500 %% 50) - 20)^2 ) >=100, 1] <- 0
 x@data@values[( ((1:2500 %/% 50 )- 30)^2 + ((1:2500 %% 50) - 20)^2 ) >=100, 2] <- 0
 x@data@values[( ((1:2500 %/% 50 )- 30)^2 + ((1:2500 %% 50) - 20)^2 ) >=100, 3] <- 0
 plotRGB(x)
 draw.circle(20,20,10,border="blue")
```

[image]

The logic is that the criteria are of the form (x-dx)^2+(y-dy)^2 > r^2 where dx and dy are the center coordinates of the circle and r is the radius == 10.

EDITS after question changed:

For each color layer, the code with named parameters would be similar to this one that makes the darkest "red". This gives a roughly circular mask although getting the centers to line up is not handled correctly:

```
x@data@values[( ((1:(height*width) %/% (height*5/4) )- (height-circley*5/4) )^2 + 
            ((1:(height*width) %% width) -       circlex )^2 ) >= radius^2, 1] <- 0
```

Further experimentation delivers this which seems pretty close:

```
x@data@values[( ((1:(height*width) %/% (height) )- (height-circley) *5/4)^2 + 
                 ((1:(height*width) %% width) -       circlex )^2 ) >= radius^2, 1] <- 0
plotRGB(x, asp=5/4, addfun=function() draw.circle(circlex,circley,radius,border="blue") )
```

Obviously you could substitute the `width/height` scaling factor for the new aspect ratio everywhere that 5/4 appears.

[image]

Comment: I updated sizes of my crop and also coordinates of the center of the circle. Would it be possible to change your code to reflect new crop size and coordinates? It would be also helpful if instead of using actual numbers (2500, 50, 30, 100 etc) you use features such as image width, height, x coordinate of the center etc...that way code will run on any image. thanks

Comment: You are the one who posed a question with no named parameters.

Comment: i tried your code...but i am not getting a circular region :( The blue circle and black area intersect quite a lot :(

Comment: Probably need to incorporate a scaling factor because the aspect ratio of the "pixels" is no longer 1.0

Comment: I am trying to test your code on a bigger image. I am reading in an JPEG image. image@data@value part doesnt have RGB values as you have shown. How should i modify `x@data@values[( ((1:2500 %/% 50 )- 30)^2 + ((1:2500 %% 50) - 20)^2 ) >=100, 1] <- 0` ?

Comment: Greyscale images do not have the three layers, but they should come in as a single column matrix. The first part of my answer showed you how to look at the structure with str()

Comment: i checked again. @file@nbands has value int 3. So I think that the image still has 3 bands. @data@values has value logi[0,0]. Therefore I am struggling to get color values. I am reading a JPEG image using `r1 <- brick("/mypath/results_circle.jpg")`

Comment: Somehow you've managed to get an empty logical matrix as the @data@values. How that happens is a puzzle that you will need to sort out. You may need to post the full output of `str(r1)` in another question. I really do think I've already answer this one fully.

Comment: Hey, i noticed that you commented on my other question and then deleted your comments. I would appreciate if you have any answer/inputs

Comment: If I knew how that happened I would have answered.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a more generic solution that also works for rasters with different coordinate systems.

The function `rasterToPoints()` converts the raster to points. Following your example, `head(rasterToPoints(x))` returns the following:

```
> head(rasterToPoints(x))
       x    y red green blue
[1,] 0.5 39.5 255   255  251
[2,] 1.5 39.5 204   205  199
[3,] 2.5 39.5 171   172  164
[4,] 3.5 39.5 157   159  148
[5,] 4.5 39.5 162   164  151
[6,] 5.5 39.5 187   189  176
```

We then need to find which points fall outside the circle and set their values to zero:

```
is_outside_circ = (rasterToPoints(x)[,1] - circlex)^2 + (rasterToPoints(x)[,2] - circley)^2 >= radius^2
x@data@values[ is_outside_circ,] <- 0
plotRGB(x)
draw.circle(circlex,circley,radius,border="blue")
```

[Result: black points outside circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFN3Z.png)